# scala: list.flatten: no implicit argument matching parameter type (Any) = > Iterable[Any] was found

Tags: scala, compilation

compiling this code in scala 2.7.6:

```
def flatten1(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = l.flatten
```

i get the error:

```
no implicit argument matching parameter type (Any) = > Iterable[Any] was found
```

why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are expecting to be able to "flatten" `List(1, 2, List(3,4), 5)` into `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, then you need something like:

```
implicit def any2iterable[A](a: A) : Iterable[A] = Some(a)
```

Along with:

```
val list: List[Iterable[Int]] = List(1, 2, List(3,4), 5) // providing type of list 
                                                         // causes implicit 
                                                         // conversion to be invoked

println(list.flatten( itr => itr )) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

**EDIT**: *the following was in my original answer until the OP clarified his question in a comment on Mitch's answer*

What are you *expecting to happen* when you `flatten` a `List[Int]`? Are you expecting the function to sum the `Int`s in the `List`? If so, you should be looking at the new aggegation functions in **2.8.x**:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
println( list.sum ) //6
```

Comment: I was interested in your original answer. Yet I can't understand why it needs to be so cumbersome.

Comment: cumbersome? why are you trying to flatten a possibly flat list? how is scala supposed to know how you want to flatten a list filled with anything?

Comment: def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = l flatMap {
      case l: List[_] => flatten(l);
      case e => List(e);
    }

Answer (score 4):

The documentation:

> Concatenate the elements of this list. The elements of this list should be a Iterables. Note: The compiler might not be able to infer the type parameter.

Pay close attention to that second sentence. `Any` cannot be converted to `Iterable[Any]`. You could have a list of `Int`s, and that list cannot be flattened since `Int` is not iterable. And think about it, if you have `List[Int]`, what are you flattening? You need `List[B <: Iterable[Any]]`, because then you would have two dimensions, which can be flattened to one.

Comment: scala> val l = List(1, 2, List(3, 4))
l: List[Any] = List(1, 2, List(3, 4))

so does this mean I can't flatten  list of Int? what lists can i flatten then?

Comment: *@Ittay* - see my answer - you need to convert the `List[Any]` which you've provided to a `List[Iterable[A]]` for some A.

Comment: you can flatten a list of iterables, i.e. a list of lists of ints.

Answer (score 0):

**flatten** does not take any arguments in Scala 3.